# Remove product category titles from shop page woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove the product category titles from my WordPress website above the product category images on this page (All products, cheeseboxes, etc):

http://www.partisan-deli.co.uk/index.php/shop/

I've seen answers to similar questions however I only want to remove the titles from this page, not from the product pages.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,

M.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: OK will do this in future ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line in your style.css file in theme folder

```
.post-type-archive ul.shop-categories li {display:none;}
```

or if you want to remove use jQuery in footer.php file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('.post-type-archive ul.shop-categories li').remove();
})
```

Comment: Please give me a correct mark by clicking the tick symbol thanks